# Why does Hibernate perform a JNDI lookup?

Tags: java, hibernate, jndi

I have following configuration file -

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="HibernateSessionFactory">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mysql</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <mapping resource="com/kshitiz/Game.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my code for building a session factory -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        sf = config.buildSessionFactory();
    }
```

I am getting this exception -

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(InitialContext.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.bind(NamingHelper.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance(SessionFactoryObjectFactory.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at com.kshitiz.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Edit:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.kshitiz.Game" table="GAME">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="date" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="DATE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My question - **Why is Hibernate trying to perform a JNDI lookup when I haven't configured anything of that sort in my project?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not actually failing because of lookup, but because it tries to make binding to JNDI. It does so because here:

```
<session-factory name="HibernateSessionFactory">
```

you give name of session factory Hibernate tries to bind session factory to JNDI. Most likely you do not have JNDI configured for your Java SE application, so name attribute is not needed. Just omit it:

```
<session-factory>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is in hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Try with this configuration.

```
 <session-factory name="java:/hibernate/SessionFactory">
   <property name="session_factory_name">java:hibernate/SessionFactory</property>
   <!-- Add your configurations -->
</session-factory>
```

Comment: That doesn't help. Same exception.

Comment: try this way , instead of this <session-factory name="java:/hibernate/SessionFactory">
 you add like this <session-factory>

Answer (score 0):

`at com.kshitiz.Main.main(Main.java:11)`

I guess the problem is here....

Can you have relook on whether there is any java file without class names? or that is not mapped in your `Game.hbm.xml`?

It is not that Hibernate will perform a JNDI lookup always. It happens only when specified.

Comment: "Can you have relook on whether there is any java file without class names?" If there were shouldn't that show some kind of mapping exception? Why a JNDI exception?