# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException with QueryDSL

Tags: java, hibernate, jndi, jpql, querydsl

I am trying to write a simple query using `QueryDSL`, but my attempt fails with the following exception.

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

I tried executing query the following ways.

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sf.openSession();

JPQLQuery query = new HibernateQuery(session);

QClient t = QClient.client;

List<Client> lst = query.from(t).list(t);
System.out.println(lst.size());
```

And another way.

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = 
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my.package.entities");

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);

    QClient t = QClient.client;

    List<Client> lst = query.from(t).list(t);
    System.out.println(lst.size());
```

As stated, both this ways failed with the same exception.

I am using Postrges DB, and the parameters are specified in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Do I need to setup something more for this to work?

Comment: Add hibernate.cfg.xml content also

Answer (score 0):

The javax.naming package comprises the JNDI API. Since it's just an API, rather than an implementation, you need to tell it which implementation of JNDI to use. The implementations are typically specific to the server you're trying to talk to.

To specify an implementation, you pass in a Properties object when you construct the InitialContext. These properties specify the implementation to use, as well as the location of the server. The default InitialContext constructor is only useful when there are system properties present, but the properties are the same as if you passed them in manually.

As to which properties you need to set, that depends on your server. You need to hunt those settings down and plug them in.

Sample:

```
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
      properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
      properties.put("jnp.socket.Factory", "org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory");
      properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://" + remoteHost + :1099");
      context = new InitialContext(properties);
```

or

look for this

[Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625131/why-does-hibernate-perform-a-jndi-lookup)